# python requests cookies date format

Tags: python, date, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I get cookies from site with the help of requests. When I print cookies keys I get the following:

```
[Cookie(version=0, name='Session', value='4safsadfsdfsdfsd06206ba8cea7c2', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.site.info', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1433352401, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False),

 Cookie(version=0, name='UserID', value='555777', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.site.info', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1433352401, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False) ]
```

What does this mean? 
expires=1433352401
what is this date format? How to convert it to usual normal date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format is a Unix epoch format as known as Unix time.

You can convert the epoch time in Python 2 by:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(cookie_time)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Cookie expires on `2015-06-03 17:26:41` which is on 3rd June.

You can run this code live here: http://ideone.com/a4eC0Y

Answer (score 2):

It is a timestamp; seconds since the epoch. You can create a `datetime` object from it with the `datetime.fromtimestamp()` method:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1433352401)
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 3, 18, 26, 41)
```

The cookie expires on June 3rd this year.